# How to set a user-style for abbreviations with glossaries-extra?

Tags: glossaries, acronyms, glossaries-extra

I used `glossaries` package to create a list of acronyms and made my own glossary style, like in MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[nopostdot,nonumberlist,acronym]{glossaries}

\newglossarystyle{acronym}
{%
    \setglossarystyle{long}
    \renewenvironment{theglossary}%
    {\begin{longtable}[l]{p{0.13\textwidth}p{0.7\textwidth}}}%
        {\end{longtable}}
}

\newacronym{PNG}{PNG}          {Portable Network Graphics }
\newacronym{SVG}{SVG}          {Scalable Vector Graphics}
\newacronym{JPEG}{JPEG}        {Joint Photographic Experts Group}

\makeglossaries

\begin{document}

    \glsaddall
    \printglossary[type=acronym,style=acronym,title={}]

    First use of \gls{JPEG} and \gls{PNG}. Second use of \gls{PNG} and \gls{JPEG}.

\end{document}
```

[image]

I started to use `glossaries-extra` package and tried to use `\newabbreviationstyle` command to adjust my style for abbreviations in `glossaries-extra`, but it fails with `Paragraph ended before \newabbreviationstyle was complete` error:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[nopostdot,nonumberlist,acronym]{glossaries-extra}

\newabbreviationstyle{acronym-user}
{%
    \setglossarystyle{long}
    \renewenvironment{theglossary}%
    {\begin{longtable}[l]{p{0.13\textwidth}p{0.7\textwidth}}}%
        {\end{longtable}}
}

\setabbreviationstyle{acronym-user}

\newabbreviation{PNG}{PNG}          {Portable Network Graphics }
\newabbreviation{SVG}{SVG}        {Scalable Vector Graphics}
\newabbreviation{JPEG}{JPEG}        {Joint Photographic Experts Group}

\makeglossaries

\begin{document}

    \glsaddall
    \printglossary[type=acronym,style=acronym-user,title={}]

    First use of \gls{JPEG} and \gls{PNG}. Second use of \gls{PNG} and \gls{JPEG}.

\end{document}
```

How to reach the same result with `glossaries-extra` package?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by redefying `\newacronym` macros with the `first` option field.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[nopostdot,nonumberlist,acronym]{glossaries-extra}

\renewcommand{\newacronym}[3]{%
    \newglossaryentry{#1}{%
        type=acronym, 
        name=#2,
        description={#3},
        first={{#3} ({#2})},
    }
}

\newglossarystyle{acronym}
{%
    \setglossarystyle{long}
    \renewenvironment{theglossary}%
    {\begin{longtable}[l]{p{0.2\textwidth}p{0.7\textwidth}}}%
        {\end{longtable}}
}


\newacronym{PNG}{PNG}          {Portable Network Graphics }
\newacronym{SVG}{SVG}        {Scalable Vector Graphics}
\newacronym{JPEG}{JPEG}        {Joint Photographic Experts Group}

\makeglossaries

\begin{document}

    \glsaddall
    \printglossary[type=acronym,style=acronym,title={}] 

    First use of \gls{JPEG} and \gls{PNG}. Second use of \gls{PNG} and \gls{JPEG}.

\end{document}
```

Comment: I doubt that this is the preferred way of using `\newacronym` -- by redefining it